# Why my NSArray sorter doesn't work?

Tags: objective-c

I have

```
        if (_sortedThemes == nil)
        {
            _sortedThemes = [[self.themes allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *str1, NSString *str2)
                             {
                                 if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"Default"] && str1 != str2)
                                 {
                                     return NSOrderedAscending;
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     return [str1 compare:str2];
                                 }
                             }];                        
        }

        for (id d in _sortedThemes)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",d);
        }
```

_sortedThemes is indeed nil and the sorter returns:

Blue, ... , Default , ....

I want Default as the first element, everything else in the regular order.

I changed to

```
if (([str1 isEqualToString:@"Default"] || [str2 isEqualToString:@"Default"]) && str1 != str2)
```

However, Default is still not the first element.

Comment: Why not just keep a special reference to `Default` instead of having it in the set (since it's special anyway)? That way you could just easily sort the array and insert `Default` at its head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"Default"] && str1 != str2)
```

"Default" could also be str2. You need to add that case, then it probably works.

Comment: I changed if (([str1 isEqualToString:@"Default"] || [str2 isEqualToString:@"Default"]) && str1 != str2), but it still doesn't work....

Comment: if the second string is equal, you probably need to return NSOrderedDescending.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code might help you

```
  NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11",@"2",@"3",@"1", nil];
[list sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSInteger firstInteger = [obj1 integerValue];
    NSInteger secondInteger = [obj2 integerValue];
    if( firstInteger > secondInteger) return NSOrderedDescending;
    if( firstInteger == secondInteger) return NSOrderedSame;
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

Comment: Does not treat "Default" special. Also always the same result for both > and < .